AzCopy fails with CannotVerifyCopySource
My AzCopy command is failing with this error:
RESPONSE 403: 403 This request is not authorized to perform this operation.
ERROR CODE: CannotVerifyCopySource
The command should be copying files from a local directory to an Azure Storage Account blob container.

I needed to update the "Permitted scope for copy operations" configuration value to "From any storage account."

